# How do rotor tangs lock into wheel keyways?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-maintenance, landing-gear

How do the rotor tangs lock into wheel keyways? Are there special keys on the outboard wheel half that allow locking the tangs in place?

Also would be great if anyone could provide me with a image of an aircraft wheel from the inboard side looking outboard.

Comment: For what aircraft?

Answer (score 3):

The tangs just slot into mating recesses in the bore of the main wheel so they can float freely laterally as they are squeezed together while transmitting torque from the wheel to the rotors.  Excuse my crude sketch:

[image]

Here's a decent cutaway:

[image]